# Two ways of implement Delegation in Swift, what is the difference?

Tags: swift, protocols, delegation

Say for example you have a protocol in Swift:

```
protocol WeatherServiceDelegate: class {   
    func didCompleteRequest(result: String)
}
```

Two ways of implementing them:

**Way 1:** Via class inheritance

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WeatherServiceDelegate {
     ....
}
```

---

**Way 2:** Via extension

However, Swift does provide a keyword `extension` which can be used to implement the protocol methods

```
extension ViewController: WeatherServiceDelegate{
    func didCompleteRequest(result: String){
        print(result)
    }
}
```

Is there any difference on those two methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between protocol, extension and category in IOS development? And how to use them appropriately?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859411/what-is-the-difference-between-protocol-extension-and-category-in-ios-developme)

Comment: @leanne I have viewed that post. This question is focusing on the diff between two ways of implementing a protocol.

Comment: There's no difference at runtime. But if you want to define and use instance variable Way 1 is your only option. Use Way 2 if you want to modularize the code, like breaking it out into multiple files (not common for a view controller)

Comment: More generally, it's not "Two Ways of Implementing Delegation", but "Two Ways of Implementing Protocol Adoption".

Answer (score 2):

Per Apple's [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html):

> Extensions add new functionality to an existing class, structure, enumeration, or protocol type. This includes the ability to extend types for which you do not have access to the original source code (known as retroactive modeling).

So it appears in your case there is little difference except in how you want to arrange your code.

Answer (score 1):

Well! There's no difference at runtime. But when adding protocol conformance to a model, prefer adding a separate extension for the protocol methods. This keeps the related methods grouped together with the protocol and can simplify instructions to add a protocol to a class with its associated methods.

**Preferred:**

```
    class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    // class stuff here
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
extension MyViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    // table view data source methods
}

// MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate
extension MyViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    // scroll view delegate methods
}
```

**Not Preferred:**

```
class MyViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UIScrollViewDelegate {
// all methods
```

}